# Number of zeroes and sign switches in a constructed zero-sum double sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

[See also MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/342451/129831).

**Setup.** Let $n\in\Bbb N$. Let $a_{1,1}, a_{1,2},\dots, a_{1,n}\in\Bbb R$ be a given sequence of real numbers that sum to $0$, i.e. $a_{1,n}=-(a_{1,1}+a_{1,2}+\dots+a_{1,n-1})$. For $i=2,\dots,n$ define
$$a_{i,j}=a_{1,j}+a_{1,j+1}+\dots+a_{1,j+i-1}=\sum_{k=j}^{j+i-1} a_{1,k}\quad(\text{for } j=1,\dots,n-i+1).$$
The "half-matrix" $(a_{i,j})_{i,j}$ can be visualized as follows:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} & \dots & a_{1,n-2} & a_{1,n-1} & -(a_{1,1}+a_{1,2}+\dots+a_{1,n-1}) \\
a_{1,1}+a_{1,2} & a_{1,2}+ a_{1,3} & a_{1,3}+a_{1,4} & \dots & a_{1,n-2} + a_{1,n-1} & -(a_{1,1}+a_{1,2}+\dots+a_{1,n-2}) \\
a_{1,1}+a_{1,2}+a_{1,3} & a_{1,2}+a_{1,3}+a_{1,4} & a_{1,3}+a_{1,4}+a_{1,5} & \dots & -(a_{1,1}+a_{1,2}+\dots+a_{1,n-3}) \\
\vdots & \vdots & ⋰& ⋰ \\
a_{1,1}+a_{1,2}+\dots+a_{1,n-1} & -a_{1,1} \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Now I have the following proposition:

> **Proposition.** Let $n, a_{i,j}$ be as in the setup. Then there are at least $n$ distinct pairs $(i,j)$ with $i\in\{1,\dots, n\}$ and $j\in\{1,\dots,n-i+1\}$ such that
>
> - $a_{i,j}=0$ **or**
> - $j\le n-i$ and $a_{i,j}\cdot a_{i,j+1} < 0$.

More informally, the number of zeros of the $a_{i,j}$ plus the number of "sign switches" between adjacent $a_{i,j}$ in all rows is at least $n$.

*My question: How can we prove this propostion?*.

---

**Context.** Proving this proposition would enable me to solve [another problem about zeroes of special continuous functions that I found on StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3366262/631742).

**Example ($n=4$).** Consider 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \frac12 & -\frac14 & -\frac54 \\
\frac32 & \frac14 & -\frac32 \\
\frac54 & -1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}

Then $a_{1,2}\cdot a_{1,3}<0$; $a_{2,2}\cdot a_{2,3}<0$; $a_{3,1}\cdot a_{3,2}<0$ and $a_{4,1}=0$. So in our example we have exactly $n$ zeros/sign switches.

---

**My work.** I tried using induction over $n$: If the Proposition is true for some $n-1\in\Bbb N$, fix some $(a_{i,j})_{i,j}$ as in the setup.

- If $a_{1,1}=0$, then the matrix obtained by cancelling the first column and last row of the $a_{i,j}$ matrix satisfies all assumptions of the Proposition and thus has at least $n-1$ zeros/sign switches. Since $a_{1,1}=0$, we have at least $n+1$ sign switches in the "full" matrix.
- If $a_{1,1}\neq 0$ **I don't know how to proceed**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a **very rigorous** proof of this Proposition based on the nice answer to this question by [Ilya Bogdanov](https://mathoverflow.net/users/17581/ilya-bogdanov) on MathOverflow. [**For his much easier to read sketch of proof, see here**](https://mathoverflow.net/a/342468/129831).

**Lemma 1.** If $n\in\Bbb N\setminus \{1\}$ and $a_1,a_2,\dots, a_n\in\Bbb R$ is such that $a_1\cdot a_n< 0$, then there is a $i\in\{1,2,\dots,n-1\}$ such that $a_i=0$ or $a_{i}\cdot a_{i+1}<0$.
*Proof.* Suppose otherwise. Let $\operatorname{sign}$ be the [Sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function). Then $$-1=\operatorname{sign}(a_1\cdot a_n)=\operatorname{sign}\big(a_1\cdot a_n\cdot\prod_{j=2}^{n-1} a_j^2\big) = \operatorname{sign}\big(\prod_{j=1}^{n-1} a_j\cdot a_{j+1}\big)=1.$$ *Contradiction.* $\square$

**Lemma 2.** Let $n\in\Bbb N\setminus\{1\}$ and $a_1,a_2,\dots, a_n\in\Bbb R$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i=0$. For $j\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ define $$c(j) = \begin{cases}j+1, & j\neq n\\1, & j=n\end{cases}.$$ Then there are two indices $i_1\neq i_2\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ such that $\forall j\in\{i_1,i_2\}\colon a_j=0\lor a_j\cdot a_{c(j)}<0$.

*Proof.* If all the $a_i$ are $0$ then we are done. Otherwise let $i$ be an index such that $a_i\neq 0$. Since the $a_i$ sum to $0$, there is an index $j\neq i$ such that $a_i\cdot a_j<0$. Suppose WLOG that $j>i$. By Lemma 1 there is a $i\le i_1< j$ such that $a_{i_1}=0$ or $a_{i_1}\cdot a_{i_1+1}<0$. If $\operatorname{sign}(a_i)=\operatorname{sign}(a_1)$ then by Lemma 1 (applied to $a_j,a_{j+1}, \dots, a_n,a_1$) there is a $j\le i_2\le n$ such that $a_{i_2}=0$ or $a_{i_2}\cdot a_{c(i_2)}<0$. Same reasoning (on the "left side") gives us an $i_2$ if $\operatorname{sign}(a_i)\neq\operatorname{sign}(a_1)$. Clearly, $i_1\neq i_2$. $\square$

*Proof of the Proposition.* Let $i\in\{1,2,\dots,n-1\}$. Define for $j=1,2,\dots,n$ a "natural continuation of the $a_{i,j}$"
$$d_{i,j} = \sum_{k=0}^{i-1} a_{1,\operatorname{mod}(j+k,n)}$$
where we use a modified $\operatorname{mod}$ function: $$\operatorname{mod}(n_1,n_2):=\begin{cases}n_1\mod n_2, & \text{if }n_1\mod n_2\neq 0 \\ n_2, & \text{if }n_1\mod n_2=0\end{cases}.$$

Some important observations (for all $i=1,2,\dots, n-1$):
\begin{align}
\tag 1 \label 1
d_{i,j} &= a_{i,j}, \text{ if } j\le n-i+1; \\
\tag 2 \label 2
d_{i,j} &=a_{1,j}+a_{1,j+1}+\dots+a_{1,n}+a_{1,1}+a_{1,2}+\dots+a_{1,j+i-1-n}
\\
&= -(a_{1,j+i-n}+a_{1,j+i-n+1}+\dots + a_{1,j-1}) = -a_{n-i,j+i-n}, \text{ if } j > n-i+1;
\\
\tag 3 \label 3
a_{i,n-i+1}&=a_{1,n-i+1}+a_{1,n-i+2}+\dots a_{1,n}=-a_{n-i,1}
\\
\tag 4 \label 4
\sum_{j=1}^n d_{i,j} &= i\cdot\sum_{j=1}^n a_{1,j} = 0.
\end{align}

Because of \eqref{3}, we can apply Lemma 2 to the $d_{i,j}$ for each $i$ and get that:

There are two functions $h_1,h_2\colon\{1,\dots,n-1\}\to \{1,\dots,n\}$ such that for all $i\in\{1,\dots,n-1\}$ we have
$$
\big(d_{i,h_1(i)}=0 \lor d_{i,h_1(i)}\cdot d_{i,\operatorname{mod}(h_1(i)+1,n)}<0\big) \land \big(d_{i,h_2(i)}=0 \lor d_{i,h_2(i)}\cdot d_{i,\operatorname{mod}(h_2(i)+1,n)}<0\big) \land h_1(i)\neq h_2(i).
$$

For every $i\in\{1,\dots,n-1\}$ we now use the following result:

- If $1\le h_1(i)<n-i+1$, then we have a zero at (using \eqref{1}) $d_{i,h_1(i)}=d_{i,h_1(i)}$ or a sign switch between $d_{i,h_1(i)}=a_{i,h_1(i)}$ and $d_{i,h_1(i)+1}=a_{i,h_1(i)+1}$.
- If $h_1(i)=n-i+1$, then we have a zero at $d_{i,h_1(i)}=a_{i,h_1(i)}$ or a sign switch between (using \eqref{1}, \eqref{2} and \eqref{3}) $d_{i,h_1(i)}=-a_{n-i,1}$ and $d_{i,h_1(i)+1}=-a_{n-i,2}$.
- If $n-i+1<h_1(i)<n$, then we have a zero at (using \eqref{2}) $d_{i,h_1(i)}=a_{n-i,h_1(i)+i-n}$ or a sign switch between $a_{n-i,h_1(i)+i-n}$ and $a_{n-i,h_1(i)+i-n+1}$.
- If $h_1(i)=n$, then we have a zero at $d_{i,n}=a_{n-i,i}$ or a sign switch between $d_{i,n}=-a_{n-i,i}$ and $d_{i,1}=a_{i,1}=-a_{n-i,n-(n-i)+1}=-a_{n-i,i+1}$.

The same reasoning applies to the function $h_2$. Let 
$$S:=\{(i,h_1(i))\mid i=1,\dots,\lceil (n-1)/2\rceil\}\cup \{(i,h_2(i))\mid i=1,\dots,\lceil (n-1)/2\rceil\}.$$
By the properties of $h_1,h_2$ (namely $h_1(i)\neq h_2(i)$), we know that the cardinality of $S$ is at least $n-1$. By using the above four reasonings, we can get a distinct pair $(\tilde i, \tilde j)$ corresponding to a zero or a sign switch for every pair $(i,j)\in S$.

So there are at least $n-1$ zeros/sign switches in the first $n-1$ rows. It follows that, since $a_{n,1}=0$, there are at least $n$ zeros/sign switches in total. $\square$